# Validar contraseña repetida en angular 2 con FormControl y Validators

Tags: angularjs-2.0, formularios, webforms

validar si el campo de "repetir contraseña" es igual a contraseña y viceversa, el punto es que no quiero usar Form Builder

Lo que llevo es la validación básica de campos requeridos con el Validatori required, estas son las clases que importe

```
import { Validators, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
```

Lo primero que hice fue crear ambos form controllers con sus validaciones

```
contrasena = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]);
repetirContrasena = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]);
```

Despues agrupe los FormControllers en un Form group

```
registroForm = new FormGroup({
    contrasena: this.contrasena,
    repetirContrasena : this.repetirContrasena,
});
```

En el HTML así declare el form

```
<form method="post" [formGroup]="registroForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >
```

Y asi fue como declare las contraseña

```
<!-- Contraseña -->
        <div class="registroFormContentInputSmall">
          <label for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
          <input id="contraseña" type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="contraseña" [formControl]="contrasena">
          <!-- Contraseña Alerts -->
          <div [hidden]="contrasena.valid || contrasena.untouched" class="alert">
            <div [hidden]="!contrasena.hasError('required')">
              - Se requiere la contraseña
            </div>
            <div [hidden]="!contrasena.hasError('minlength')">
              - Se requieren 6 carácteres o más
            </div>
            <div [hidden]="!contrasena.hasError('contrasenaDiferente')">
              - Las contraseñas no coinciden
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- Repetir Contraseña -->
        <div class="registroFormContentInputSmall registroFormContentInputSmallMargin">
          <label>Confirmar contraseña</label>
          <input type="password" name="repetirContrasena" placeholder="repetir contraseña" [formControl]="repetirContrasena">
          <!-- RepetirContraseña Alerts -->
          <div [hidden]="repetirContrasena.valid || repetirContrasena.untouched" class="alert">
            <div [hidden]="!repetirContrasena.hasError('required')">
              - Se requiere la contraseña
            </div>
            <div [hidden]="!repetirContrasena.hasError('minlength')">
              - Se requieren 6 carácteres o más
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Eh estado intentando agregar un Validator que yo hice a travez de un función pero no puedo resolver el problema y me gustaría saber como agregar esa validación de comparar las contraseñas y ver si son iguales o no.

Answer (score 2):

> Paso 1: Importar módulos.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class TuModulo {}
```

> Paso 2: Crear función de validación para formularios.

```
import { ValidatorFn, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

function equalsValidator(otherControl: AbstractControl): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    const value: any = control.value;
    const otherValue: any = otherControl.value;
    return otherValue === value ? null : { 'notEquals': { value, otherValue } };
  };
}

export const CustomValidators = {
  equals: equalsValidator
};
```

> Paso 3: Crear formulario y asignar validadores en el ViewModel.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tu-componente',
  templateUrl: './tu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tu.component.css']
})
export class TuComponent {

  formGroup: FormGroup | null = null;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      password: ['', [Validators.required]],
      repeat_password: ''
    });

    this.formGroup.get('repeat_password').setValidators(
      CustomValidators.equals(this.formGroup.get('password'))
    );
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    const password = this.formGroup.get('password').value as string;
    // Tú lógica de negocio...
  }
}
```

> Paso 4: Vincular formulario y controles en la View.

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" [formControl]="formGroup.controls['password']">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Repetir Contraseña" [formControl]="formGroup.controls['repeat_password']">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">Guardar cambios</button>
</form>
```